# How to go (seek) particular timestamp on Video in React native (Expo)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using the expo-cli for application and I am using expo install expo-av for display video in application.

I need functionality, when i click on button to directly got particular time (Ex. 5 minutes)

For example:
Video length is 28 seconds and i Have button to go to 15 second. So when i click this button to this time and then play

Here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Video, AVPlaybackStatus } from 'expo-av';

export default function App() {
  const video = React.useRef(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({});

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Video
        ref={video}
        style={styles.video}
        source={{
          uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        }}
        useNativeControls
        resizeMode="contain"
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
      />
      <View style={styles.buttons}>
        <Button
          title={status.isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}
          onPress={() =>
            status.isPlaying ? video.current.pauseAsync() : video.current.playAsync()
          }
        />
      </View>
      <Button
        title={'Goto to 15 seconds'}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log("status.positionMillis --> ", status.positionMillis)
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  video: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 320,
    height: 200,
  },
  buttons: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am a bit late to this question, but I suggest that you use `positionMillis`.

```
     <Video
        ref={video}
        style={styles.video}
        source={{
          uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        }}
        useNativeControls
        resizeMode="contain"
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
        positionMillis={this.state.time} //set to whatever you want
      />
```